# What is the difference between x = y = 0 and x = 0 y = 0 in Python

Tags: python, variable-assignment

In python, what is the difference between

```
x = y = 0
```

and

```
x = 0
y = 0
```

Comment: One of them is a single line, the other is two lines. That's the difference. In other cases (e.g. when assigning mutable objects like lists) there would be a difference.

Comment: Even for immutable objects it won't be the same thing (i.e. `x is y` may return `False` for the latter). Technically speaking the exact equivalent would be `y = 0` then `x = y`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIRC, there's no difference for immutable types (like int in the example). But beware of potential issues when doing chained assignment for mutables:

```
>>> foo = bar = []
>>> print(id(foo) == id(bar))

Out: True

>>> foo.append(1)
>>> bar

Out: [1]
```

So here you inadvertently modify both lists since they both refer to the same set of memory addresses.

EDIT:
Actually, there is a difference in your example. The one-liner chained assignment is more compact but might become less legible so I personally almost never use those.